# Encode function data using Truffle

Tags: solidity, truffle, hardhat

How do you encode function data using Truffle?
In hardhat i can use:

```
const encodedFunctionCall = smartcontract.interface.encodeFunctionData("functionName", [data]);
```

If i try the same in Truffle it tells me interface is undefined, how does it work?

Thats how i deploy my smart contract in the test file:

```
smartcontract = await Smartcontract.deployed();
```

Answer (score 0):

With truffle you have to use web3's `encodeABI`, from this issue https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/issues/1230:

`const encodedFunctionCall = smartcontract.contract.methods.functionName(data).encodeABI();`